# How can I make sure that BDE *.MB files are being deleted once I finish my Delphi app?

Tags: delphi, bde

I'm working on a Delphi 4 application (Don't ask me why, I already know it's so old but I had to, it's more complex to explain this, just boss demands).

This Delphi application creates a lot of *.MB files on execution (All good for now), it uses many TQueries, TUpdatesSQL, TDataSource so I guess it's normal. But when I close this app, those files should be deleted (but no), then when I open this app for a second time (third, fourth, etc.) it creates more and more *.MB files, finally ending with an error: 
**"Too many open files. You may need to increase MAXFILEHANDLE limit in IDAPI configuration"**

I just found on internet that you have to increase the MaxFileHandles (I have value of 48) at:

```
 BDE Administrator:
 Configuration->System->INIT->MAXFILHANDLES
```

I this the only solution? or there is another one?
Can anyone give me a light, or a tip for deleting those files when the app is closed?

Comment: What does the "(but no)" in "should be deleted (but no)" mean?  Increasing the number of file handles in the BDE config is only going to delay the onset of the problem, not overcome it.  Make sure your app closes all open datasets (TQueries and TTables) before it closes (and make sure you have no open datasets in the IDE when your project is open).  Then, if you really want to delete the data files, you could use the DeleteFile function on the SysUtils unit.

Comment: Thank you for your repply, sorry, my english isn't good, I just want to say that those files should be deleted but they don't

Comment: They won't be deleted unless you take specific steps to delete them. Merely closing a TTable, or TQuery, does not delete the data files(s) on disk. Btw see TTable.DeleteTable and .DeleteIndex in the Online Help.

Comment: You can write code that deletes them when your app is being closed. Changing the maximum number of file handles will not solve the problem, any more than putting a piece of tape on your dashboard to hide the *check engine* light will keep you from breaking down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A correctly written and correctly used D4 program should not leave behind
.MB files in the way you describe.

I strongly urge you to follow the procedure I describe below so that you can satisfy
yourself that stray .MB files should not be left behind in normal operation; hopefully, once you have, it should be fairly straightforward to track down why they're getting left behind in your case.

1. Create a new project folder, call it D:\Test on your development drive and copy the
   files of an existing Paradox database into it.  I used the Venues database which in
   D7 (I do not have an earlier version available) is in Delphi's Shared\Data folder.
   It consists of the data file Venues.DB, the index Venues.PX and the memos file Venues.MB.
   If D4 doesn't come with the Venues database, use another one.  By the way, the point
   of copying the database files to the new project folder is that the database is quite
   likely to get damaged in the course of what follows.
2. Using the BDE Configuration program, create a new Standard, Paradox alias and point it at the project folder.
3. Start D4 and create a new project which includes a TDataBase, TQuery, TDataSource and a TDBGrid
   to display the TQuery's database.  Set the TQuery's SQL property to

   select * from venues
4. Important: when you save the project, make sure the TDataBase's Connected property
   is set to False and the TQuery's Active property is also False. Insert code in the FormCreate
   event to open Query1.
5. Open a CMD window on your project directory.
6. Compile and run the program.
7. While the program is open do a

   dir *.mb

at the CMD prompt.

You should see

> Venues.MB

and a file with a name like

> _QSQ1.MB

which is a temporary .MB file the BDE has opened for Query1.

8. Close the program and repeat step 7.

You should now only see

> Venues.MB

listed because the BDE code has closed and deleted the temporary .MB file.  That
is what is **supposed** to happen.

9. Run the program again. and this time, after its form opens, press Ctrl-F2
   to reset it (force it to close without executing its normal shut-down code.
10. Repeat step 7 and you should find there are two .MB files

> Venues.MB

and the temporary file with a name like

> _QSQ1.MB

because the BDE code didn't have a chance to remove the temporary .MB file

11. If you keep repeating steps 9 and 10, you'll find that an extra .MB file
    gets left behind (with an increasing number on the end of its name),
    which is why the BDE eventually complains that you've run out of file handles.
12. I'm afraid **your** task is to work out why this is happening:

- It may be simply that you are in the habit of doing a Ctrl-F2 to terminate the
  program, in which case the solution is obvious, don't!
- Otherwise something must be going wrong as the program closes.  It could be any
  one of a number of things, but only you can see your code.  What I would be looking
  for is something like an exception handler that has been set up in the FormClose event
  to suppress an unwanted exception during shutdown.  This sort of "fast fix" which
  was intended to hide a problem without finding and fixing the problem causing
  it was fairly common in the D4 era.

Anyway, good luck!  With a bit of systematic debugging, hopefully you won't need it/

Comment: Hey Martin, thank you, I just did the debugging being the most patientful guy ever (The program is really complex) and I just figured out that there were a lot of instances without a .free

Comment: Great, glad you fixed it!